# dired-sidebar not working

Tags: debugging, dired-sidebar

My `dired-sidebar` no longer works. For the commands `dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar` and `dired-sidebar-show-sidebar` they both give:

```
 Wrong type argument: stringp, (Git "~/")
```

Anyone know the reason and fix? MacOS 14, Emacs 29 (recent build)

This is the trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp (Git "~/"))
  dired-sidebar-get-dir-to-show()
  dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar()
  funcall-interactively(dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar)
  command-execute(dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar" "dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar" "dired-sidebar-toggle-sidebar")
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

This is reproducible with only using the package `dired-sidebar` in my `init.el`.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: just `emacs -Q` then load only that package. Please add this info to the question itself, to make clear that nothing else is involved. (Comments can be deleted at any time, and comments are searchable; questions need to stand on their own.) Thx.